# 'Package Does Not Exist' Error When Compiling With Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, javac

I have an ant build script that is responsible for compiling and packaging my project. When it gets to the compile task, the build fails with a bunch of 'error: package 'X' does not exist'
errors. I thought it might be the classpath, so I added an echo to print out the classpath before the compile runs. The supposedly missing jars are all there. I'm not sure what else the issue could be. Any help would be great.

**My build.xml**

```
<macrodef name="compile">
        <attribute name="src" />
        <attribute name="dst" />
        <attribute name="groovyc" default="false" />
        <echo>Compiling without groovy support</echo>
        <property name="myclasspath" refid="build.classpath"/>
        <echo message="Compile classpath= ${myclasspath}"/>
        <javac classpathref="build.classpath" includeantruntime="false" destdir="@{dst}" debug="${javac.debug}"  deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" target="${compiler.target}" nowarn="on" verbose="false">
                        <src path="@{src}" />
                        <compilerarg line="-proc:none" />
        </javac>
</macrodef>
```

**Classpath Output**

> Compile classpath=
>   /media/psf/Home/Documents/workspace/optics/Builder/lib/hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.2.0.Final.jar:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jboss-common-core/2.5.0.Final/jboss-common-core-2.5.0.Final.jar:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/dbunit/dbunit/2.7.0/dbunit-2.7.0.jar:**/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar**:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.17/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi/3.17/poi-3.17.jar:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.1/commons-collections4-4.1.jar:/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.17/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar

**Error Message**

```
[javac] /media/psf/Home/Documents/workspace/optics/Common/src/com/tura/common/CircularByteBuffer.java:22: error: package org.apache.commons.collections does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferOverflowException;
[javac]                                      ^
[javac] /media/psf/Home/Documents/workspace/optics/Common/src/com/tura/common/CircularCharBuffer.java:22: error: package org.apache.commons.collections does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferOverflowException;
[javac]                                      ^
[javac] /media/psf/Home/Documents/workspace/optics/Common/src/com/tura/common/CircularObjectBuffer.java:3: error: package org.apache.commons.collections does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferOverflowException;
[javac]
```

Comment: That class is in the bold jar. Try deleting that folder and see if maven correctly downloads it if you try again.

Comment: @elliott-frisch No luck. The jar is there, ant just doesn't seem to see it.

Comment: There's probably some small difference in the file name or path. Can you show the output of `ls` in `/home/pbuchheit/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/` as well as the part of your build script that defines `build.classpath`?